# How to get my logo to center?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a logo that I'm trying to center in my sidebar when viewed in the **mobile phone** size. Right now it stays flush to the left side of the sidebar. You can see it [live here](http://www.ogmda.com/test/menu.html).

Here's my html code:

```
<aside class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-inner"><a href="#"><img src="img/kobe_logo.png" class="phone-logo visible-phone"></a>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#" style="color: #999;"><i class="icon-time icon-2x icon-white"></i> <span class="misc"><strong>Open Everyday! 11am - 10pm</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" style="color: #999;" class="visible-desktop visible-tablet"><i class="icon-phone-sign icon-2x"></i> <span class="misc"><strong>(512)&nbsp;288-7333</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tel:+15122887333" class="visible-phone"><i class="icon-phone-sign icon-2x"></i> <span class="misc"><strong>(512)&nbsp;288-7333</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Kobe+Japanese+Steakhouse&hl=en&cid=14743286964168532232&gl=US&t=m&z=16&iwloc=A"><i class="icon-flag icon-2x icon-white"></i> <span class="misc"><strong>Locate KOBE</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Kobe-Japanese-Steakhouse-Austin-Texas/308215040224"><i class="icon-facebook-sign icon-2x icon-white"></i> <span class="misc"><strong>See KOBE on Facebook!</strong></span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Note: *This problem only exists when viewed in the mobile phone layout. I have this specific logo position hidden when viewed in larger size.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving class="logo_sidebar" to the containing link tag

```
<a href="#/" class="logo_sidebar"><img src="img/kobe_logo.png"></a>
```

and replacing .logo_sidebar in your css file with this:

```
.logo_sidebar {text-align:center; display:block;}
.logo_sidebar img {margin:2.3em 0 2em; }
```

Comment: sorry I posted the wrong code section in my original post. Can you check the updated code? Thank you.

Comment: The same should still apply to your updated code. Just try adding text-align:center; display:block; to the <a> tag, and you can apply the margin to the image.